# Mobius transformation $0$ to $2$, $-2i$ to $0$ and $i$ to $\frac32$.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I want to determine the Mobius tranformation mapping $0$ to $2$, $-2i$ to $0$ and $i$ to $\frac32$.

I don't know how to do this at all. I am fairly sure what I want is a composition of easier mappings, but having no examples I don't know what to do.

Also, how do I plot this shift? Will it still be 2D? or Can I have a 3D mapping representing the change.

---

Also a side comment on a good reference text for this would be nice(but isn't the question here as it is opinionated.)

---

Should I be getting the $a,b,c,d$ in terms of one another? Also are mobius transforms unique?

Answer (score 2):

A Mobius tranformation has the form
$$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d},\qquad ad-bc\ne 0.$$
Apply the hypothesis:
$$\frac{a0+b}{c0+d} = f(0) = 2,$$
$$\cdots$$
And solve the system of equations (How? Three equations and four unknowns!)

Comment: Is the check for non-degeneracy a coincidence ?

Comment: Also is this a mapping $f:\Bbb C^* \to \Bbb C^*$?

Comment: @Candygirl16, non-degeneracy isn't terribly important here, the fact that different 4-tuples $a,b,c,d$ can give the same $f$ is important. If $\Bbb C^* = \Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, yes.

Comment: It wasn't  but thanks, I'll use $C_\infty$ for that notation

Comment: @Candygirl16, if $\Bbb C^* = \Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, is false because $f(-2i)=0$.

Comment: Yes of course, I realised my silliness afterwards

Comment: Is the key to finding the solution the $\pm$ I can get from roots?

Comment: @Candygirl16, ????? the system is linear in $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Sorry, I imagined using $i^2$ I could get roots, but this is probably untrue. Then my final guess is that the transform can be 'undone' and hence I have another equation, is this the case?

Comment: @Candygirl16, $i^2 = -1$ and the inverse of $f$ will be a Mobius transformatuon.

Comment: Thank you I did it and confirmed my answer in the next question I posted and it was right.