# Möbius transform answer check for $0$ to $2$,$-2i$ to $0$, $i$ to $\frac32$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, mobius-inversion

[Continuation of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208801/mobius-transformation-0-to-2-2i-to-0-and-i-to-frac32)

---

Is this the correct answer for the möbius transformation corresponding to:

$0$ to $2$

$-2i$ to $0$

$i$ to $\frac32$

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\cong \frac{az+2azi}{az+ai}=1+\frac{ai}{az+ai}$$

Comment: Yes!!!!.. It is Correct

Comment: Yay! Why can $a$ be anything, that is weird!

Comment: Nope. $a$ can't be zero (see that). Once it is nonzero, you can cancel it out from top and bottom.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Oh woops I see, $a\ne 0 \implies1+\frac{i}{z+i}$

Comment: yeah... right .